# Definition of limit points and isolated points

Tags: analysis, limits

Definition of isolated points: If the points $p \in E \subset X$ is not a limit point, then $p$ is called isolated point of $E$.
My question is..
Then all the points in open set is called interior points and isolated points at the same time? In other words are isolated point and interior point equivalent in open set?

Comment: What makes you think a limit point can't also be an interior point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All points in an open set are interior points.  All interior points will be limit points, though not all limit points will necessarily be interior points.

No point in an open set will be an isolated point.